# Incorporating 'findnext' function into existing 'find' code?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I've VBA code that is working and displaying the first match within a UserForm.

When calling the search, the user is presented a userform and focus is on a ComboBox which requires the user to select an option, and enter a search term in a TextBox (called TextBox1 for ease). They click 'Search' and the first match details are displayed in numerous other (disabled) TextBoxes within the form.

```vb
Private Sub btnDemProg_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please select a column.")
        ComboBox1.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter a search criterium.")
        TextBox1.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim sh As Worksheet, colFnd As Range, crit As Range
    Set sh = Sheets("DEMANDS")
    Set colFnd = sh.Rows(1).find(ComboBox1.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not colFnd Is Nothing Then
        Set crit = sh.Columns(colFnd.Column).find(TextBox1.Value, , xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not crit Is Nothing Then
            With sh
                Me.DmdNo.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 1)
                Me.DmdDate.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 2)
                Me.nsn.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 3)
                Me.PTNum.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 4)
                Me.desc.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 5)
                Me.qty.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 6)
                Me.DofQ.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 7)
                Me.RDD.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 8)
                Me.Sect.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 18)
                Me.POC.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 20)
                Me.ainu.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 21)
                Me.inv.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 22)
                Me.trilogy.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 17)
                Me.ACtailNo.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 16)
                Me.TechDoc.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 28)
                Me.ACSys.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 19)
                Me.ADF_LIM_Number.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 25)
                Me.SNOW.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 26)
                Me.reason.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 27)
                Me.ProgText.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 31)
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "I cannot find this demand. Has it been cancelled/satisfied?"
        End If
    End If
```

How do I implement a 'find next' function within the existing code so that when a user clicks the search button a second (or third, or fourth etc.) time, it displays the next match of details within the userform, and if no additional matches are found, displays a MsgBox advising "No further matches found"?

I've seen and used the find next VBA function previously, but not in this context and not when I have a userform to fill with the new results.

Comment: Use `FindNext` jnside a while loop. There is an example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Private Range Variable

- Since you're exiting the procedure after each search, `FindNext` cannot help you.
- `Private crit As Range` is used to store the current found cell (range) to be used as the `After` (2nd) parameter of the `Find` method for the next search (between subsequent calls of the procedure).
- `xlFormulas` is allowing rows to be hidden.
- Not tested.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private crit As Range

Private Sub btnDemProg_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please select a column.")
        ComboBox1.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter a search criterium.")
        TextBox1.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim sh As Worksheet, colFnd As Range, CheckRow As Long
    Set sh = Sheets("DEMANDS")
    Set colFnd = sh.Rows(1).Find(ComboBox1.Value, , xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    If Not colFnd Is Nothing Then
        With sh.Columns(colFnd.Column)
            If crit Is Nothing Then
                Set crit = .Find(TextBox1.Value, , xlFormulas, xlPart)
            Else
                If Intersect(.Offset, crit) Is Nothing Then
                    Set crit = .Find(TextBox1.Value, , xlFormulas, xlPart)
                Else
                    CheckRow = crit.Row
                    Set crit = .Find(TextBox1.Value, crit, xlFormulas, xlPart)
                End If
            End If
        End With
        If Not crit Is Nothing Then
            If crit.Row > CheckRow Then
                With sh
                    Me.DmdNo.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 1)
                    Me.DmdDate.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 2)
                    Me.nsn.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 3)
                    Me.PTNum.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 4)
                    Me.desc.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 5)
                    Me.qty.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 6)
                    Me.DofQ.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 7)
                    Me.RDD.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 8)
                    Me.Sect.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 18)
                    Me.POC.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 20)
                    Me.ainu.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 21)
                    Me.inv.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 22)
                    Me.trilogy.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 17)
                    Me.ACtailNo.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 16)
                    Me.TechDoc.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 28)
                    Me.ACSys.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 19)
                    Me.ADF_LIM_Number.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 25)
                    Me.SNOW.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 26)
                    Me.reason.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 27)
                    Me.ProgText.Value = .Cells(crit.Row, 31)
                End With
            Else
                Set crit = Nothing
                MsgBox "No further matches found."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "I cannot find this demand. Has it been cancelled/satisfied?"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```